# SSRS REPORT BUILDER, Comparing two diffrent data sets in one Tablix, Expression

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I have two datasets and want to compare them in an expression.

I would like to do something like this:
=iif(Fields!Grade.Value = "ONGRADE" > LookupSet(Fields!Grade.Value = "ONGRADE", Fields!grade.Value = "ONGRADE" , Fields!grade.Value = "ONGRADE", "Previous3Week"), "UP" ,"DOWN")

This currently returns "Error" within the "ONGRADE" row.

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue little more so it will be easy to help . Like where are you using the expression, which component.

Comment: Trying to use it inside of Report Builder, to compare a row of data to a previous 3 week. Would essentially be a trend. the data is a percentage.. Just need it to say if it is UP or Down from previous 3 week data. Each data is in its own dataset.

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind your component with one of the datasets and then accordingly you can write following expression :

**=iif(Fields!grade.Value > (Fields!grade.Value, "ONGRADE_DataSet2") , "UP", "DOWN")**

in this example, the component is binded with the first dataset and the second dataset is getting referred.
This may help.

Comment: Bind? elaborate?

Comment: Tie your Tablix to one of the datasets and then write above expression.